# Angular 6 Unit testing : Empty test suite

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, karma-webpack

Under my Angular 6 app i'm using karma for unit testing , this is my config :

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },

    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
      ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
      : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 10000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
    flags: [
      '--disable-web-security',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--no-sandbox'
    ],
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity
  });
};
```

**and here is my test file :**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AdvancedSearchCrmdFormComponent } from './advanced-search-crmd-form.component';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {AdvancedSearchCrmdActionsService} from '../../advanced-search-crmd-services/advanced-search-crmd-actions.service';

describe('AdvancedSearchCrmdFormComponent', () => {
  let comp: AdvancedSearchCrmdFormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AdvancedSearchCrmdFormComponent>;

  // Test Suite of Component compiling
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AdvancedSearchCrmdFormComponent ],
      providers: [ActivatedRoute , AdvancedSearchCrmdActionsService]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AdvancedSearchCrmdFormComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    // fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  // Test case of component compilation
  it('AdvancedSearchCrmdFormComponent should be defined', () => {
    expect(comp).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

And as you can see i ve one test case to run , but i obtain this:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /home/khalidvm/Desktop/WebStorm-181.5281.31/plugins/js-karma/js_reporter/karma-intellij/lib/intellijRunner.js --karmaPackageDir=/media/khalidvm/SecondDisk/SOCLE_RCD/Front/Frontend_v3_crmd/node_modules/@angular/cli --serverPort=9876 --protocol=http: --urlRoot=/ "--testName=AdvancedSearchCrmdFormComponent "
Empty test suite.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Suggestions ?